# закрытие меню по клику вне блока. не работает кнопка закрытия

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, menu

Уже в отчаянии. Не знаю, что делать :-( Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть мобильное меню. По клику вне меню, меню закрывается, все хорошо. Используется стандартное решение для этого. Но на данном меню есть так же кнопка закрытия, "крестик". И эта кнопка работает не совсем корректно. Это заключается в том, что открытие/закрытие меню сработает по клику на этот крестик, но только если клик произойдет в любую верхнюю или нижнюю область, кроме центра. В центре текст "меню". Я уже по "всякому" пробовал играться с кодом. И никакого результата, к моему сожалению. Помогите, пожалуйста..

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
     $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
    if (!$(".header_content_one_menu").is(e.target) && $(".header_content_one_menu").has(e.target).length === 0) {
       $('#header_menu_adaptive').prop('checked', false);
    } 
    
    if (!$(".header_content_one_menu").is(e.target) && $(".header_menu_adaptive_button").has(e.target).length !== 0) {
       $('#header_menu_adaptive').prop('checked', true);
    }  
  });
  
});
```

```css
#header_menu_adaptive {
    display: none;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999999;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button > span {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.05s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button> span::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(0);
    visibility: visible;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    visibility: visible;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
    content: '';
    top: 28px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #B72A20;
    transition-duration: .25s;
}

#header_menu_adaptive:checked ~ .header_content_one_menu {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button > span, .header_menu_adaptive_button> span::before, .header_menu_adaptive_button > span::after {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #B72A20;
    font-family: RobotoCondensed;
    letter-spacing: 2.4px;
    transition-duration: .25s;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 11112;
}

.header_menu_adaptive_button > span::before {
    content: '';
    bottom: 29px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #B72A20;
    transition-duration: .25s;
}



.header_content_one_menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition-duration: .25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="header_menu_adaptive" type="checkbox">
<label class="header_menu_adaptive_button" for="header_menu_adaptive">
                        <span>меню</span>
</label>
<ul class="header_content_one_menu">                       
<li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">111</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">222</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">333</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">444</a></li><li class=""><a href="" class="header_content_one_menu_unit">555</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить вот таким способом:

```js
if (!$(".header_content_one_menu").is(event.target) && $(".header_content_one_menu").has(event.target).length === 0  && $(".header_menu_adaptive_button").has(event.target).length === 0) {
       $('#header_menu_adaptive').prop('checked', false);
}
```